# VB, How to set textbox value using webbrowser

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Can anyone tell me how can I set TextBox value using WebBrowser control?

Code:

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://signup")

    Do Until WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop


    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("MemberName").SetAttribute("value", "Luxury_UAE_AE@outlook.com")

    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("iSignupAction").InvokeMember("Click")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebBrowser1.GetElementById("MemberName").InnerText = "Luxury_UAE_AE@outlook.com"

Comment: Ahmed Can you check this one please [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63531840/vb-net-how-to-select-dropdown-using-webbrowser)